NextAuth does not redirect to Google Login in production
I have a NextJS application running on a windows server (node version 22.2.0) and I'm using NextAuth for Google Authentification for a limited number of accounts (external mode in google provider). Database is in MSSQL via prisma.
This works perfect locally with remote database, but as I have this app now in production, the redirect to the google Login doesn't work. It just stays on NextAuth default provider selection (no custom login page). In the URL, I can see the body changing, but it is not opening the Google Login page.
Even the NextAuth debugs looking OK to me:
Redirect Callback: { url: '/', baseUrl: 'https://XXX.XXX.XXX' }
Redirect Callback: { url: '/', baseUrl: 'https://XXX.XXX.XXX' }
Redirect Callback: { url: '/', baseUrl: 'https://XXX.XXX.XXX' }
[next-auth][debug][CREATE_STATE] { value: '4T9SHczCWABapR57lRH7GxIreqgt1NtZBowRz5eHz3194o', maxAge: 900 }
[next-auth][debug][CREATE_PKCECODEVERIFIER] { value: 'yrHxwSChtw7oN-f3VymqVp7I0nJE4U052wO9tZt3ndk', maxAge: 900 }
[next-auth][debug][GET_AUTHORIZATION_URL] {
  url: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=193456009801-t513geo4qhwt190v38226opnjjo47e15.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=openid%20email%20profile&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpenman.shadow-me.de%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fgoogle&access_type=offline&prompt=consent&state=4T9SHczCWABapR57lRH7GxIdt1wthBowRz5eHz3194o&code_challenge=dAOFHP2nLVlJ3Bie1iSpqrvTWwthtf0LO7XKDoY65t0&code_challenge_method=S256',
  cookies: [
    {
      name: '__Secure-next-auth.state',
      value: 'eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMhgtwMjU2R0NNIn0..pNTKB9cSikbAIxlm.y9L6Up1-E_bi6qTpHCHRO-7sPPF4H2tLtYdDvRSW4kHL45ewajBSnpy2u06GAT16cwthhiRHapz3QaxdudAGXbUgwG-BDHDF2kUFJw5Mg6YTFtiry_lJt9proDyiubHzevXJyKM90nhtwrwrhRSMO0KQPxcTVOjJv56l2Sqpyp2azLaxI8eTk.9jW30fSMLr7zJYHUAori6A',
      options: [Object]
    },
    {
      name: '__Secure-next-auth.pkce.code_verifier',
      value: 'eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlwhtriJBMjU2R0NNIn0..-qvk1CrJfR4EJdfl.FwTLyLcQkp2wtgwrthA4tEYhpQNgA24n_ggYCOeeqw9uvXEQGX0NKOvyLvX1EAe_KEwJ4NiGRyJgE3YDIA1Ta7wtrhgqb4mmoqngv-R76t_K9jtSfMCns-YLNV8X3sqv9p1ANZwwNwrthSVpdnqOcN-lbiPZGzYuZL2rP1ZzPBi1thp1bS4A.-CE4v5DK8AVJNEVHcfcB6w',
      options: [Object]
    }
  ],
  provider: {
    id: 'google',
    name: 'Google',
    type: 'oauth',
    wellKnown: 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration',
    authorization: { params: [Object] },
    idToken: true,
    checks: [ 'pkce', 'state' ],
    profile: [Function: profile],
    style: { logo: '/google.svg', bg: '#fff', text: '#000' },
    clientId: '193456009801-t513geo4qr441whrt226opnjjo47e15.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    clientSecret: 'GOCSPX-8MmHqhd6HakcwrthelEP8wjb2e5',
    signinUrl: 'https://XXX.XXX.XXX/api/auth/signin/google',
    callbackUrl: 'https://XXX.XXX.XXX/api/auth/callback/google'
  }
}
Redirect Callback: {
  url: '/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=193456009801-t513geo4qrgraev38226opnjjo47e15.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=openid+email+profile&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FXXX.XXX.XXX%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Fcallback%2Fgoogle&access_type=offline&prompt=consent&state=4T9SHczCWABapR57lRH7GwthrwtZBowRz5eHz3194o&code_challenge=dAOFHP2nLVlJ3Bie1iSpqrvTWv9hZf0LO7XKDoY65t0&code_challenge_method=S256',
  baseUrl: 'https://XXX.XXX.XXX'
}
Redirect Callback: {
  url: '/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=193456009801-t513geo4qr441rtsh226opnjjo47e15.apps.googleusercontent.com',
  baseUrl: 'https://XXX.XXX.XXX'
}

Here is my NextAuth configuration:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import prisma from "@/prisma/client";

const handler = NextAuth({
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          scope: "openid email profile",
          access_type: "offline",
          prompt: "consent",
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  debug: true,
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      console.log("SignIn Callback:", {
        user,
        account,
        profile,
        email,
        credentials,
      });
      return true;
    },
    async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
      console.log("Redirect Callback:", { url, baseUrl });
      return url.startsWith(baseUrl) ? url : baseUrl;
    },
    async session({ session, user, token }) {
      console.log("Session Callback:", { session, user, token });
      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
      console.log("JWT Callback:", {
        token,
        user,
        account,
        profile,
        isNewUser,
      });
      return token;
    },
  },
});

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

I double checked a hundred times the google redirect URI and the client ID and client secret. They are even correct in the body while clicking "Sign in with google". I don't know if the subdomain is somehow relevant, but app and auth are running on the same subdomain
Hope you can help me
Edit: Days of research made me realize this needs to be caused by IIS reverse proxy and URL rewriting. So basically all requests were rewritten to the domain defined in IIS. This works fine for all the application pages, but also for next auch which is not intended. Can somebody please support me how to configure IIS the right way to avoid rewriting for auto requests?
Solution:
uncheck the option "reverse rewrite host in response headers" in the IIS settings to avoid rewriting google links

You can refer to this tutorial to host a Node.js application on Windows with IIS as reverse proxy. If you need to filter specific requests for rewriting, you need to configure the matching rules according to your situation.

thanks. I know this tutorial, but this issue is not adressed there. But I finally solved the issue by unchecking "reverse rewrite host in response headers" in the IIS proxy configuration

Glad your issue was resolved.
